# Display two schema fields as concatenated label in KeystoneJS

Tags: reactjs, keystonejs

I am setting up my schemas and AdminUI in KeystoneJS (v6). I work with names and want to display the combined first and last name in the Select field in the frontend:

So instead of having 'Tommy', 'Markus' and so on, I want 'Tommy Smith', 'Markus Brown'.

[image: Current frontend]

This is the code I have:

```
import { list } from '@keystone-next/keystone/schema';
import { text } from '@keystone-next/fields';

export const Participant = list({
  ui: {
    labelField: 'firstName',
  },
  // fields
  fields: {
    firstName: text({ isRequired: true }),
    lastName: text({ isRequired: true }),
    }),
  },
});
```

Does anyone have any pointers how I could do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting related items in Keystone, the Admin UI uses item *labels* – a human readable identifier assigned to each item.
The value used for the item label is controlled using the `ui.labelField` list config:

> `ui.labelField`: Selects the field which will be used as the label column in the Admin UI. By default looks for a field called 'label', then falls back to 'name', then 'title', and finally 'id', which is guaranteed to exist.
>
> – [Keystone 6: Schema API docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/schema#ui)

In your example, you've configured Keystone to use the `firstName` field as the label, which works ok, but presents the problem you've identified.
What we really need is 3rd field that combines both the first and last names together.

Now, we could do this with hooks, by combining the values and saving them to another `text` field for example.
But this would duplicate the data and we'd need to remember to keep the values in sync, adding complexity.
Better to just concatenate these values when they're being read out of the DB.
For this, we can use [virtual fields](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/fields#virtual).

In the example given, the virtual field solution looks like this:

```js
import { list, graphql } from '@keystone-next/keystone';
import { text, relationship, virtual } from '@keystone-next/keystone/fields';

export const Participant = list({
  ui: {
    // Configure the list to use the fullName field for it's labels
    labelField: 'fullName',
  },
  fields: {
    firstName: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    lastName: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    // Add a fullName field that concatenates the participants first and last names together
    fullName: virtual({
      field: graphql.field({
        type: graphql.String,
        resolve: (item) => `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`,
      }),
    }),
  },
});
```

Easy, right? Then, in the Admin UI, you'll get something like this:

[image]

By default, the label is also used in the list view so you'll notice the extra info there are well:

[image]

If you don't want this, you can additionally set the `ui.listView.initialColumns` list config (docs [here](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/schema#ui)).

There's a pretty good [guide on virtual fields](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/virtual-fields) that's worth a look.
It covers more advanced usage, like loading fields from other items, returning complex types, etc.

Comment: Oh @kftb, you may also notice the `isRequired` field config is now placed within a `validation` object. This change was made in `v26` of the `@keystone-next/keystone` package (released early October). You should upgrade if possible though I believe virtual fields were working at that point in time so the, with a few tweaks, the solution above should still work for you.

Comment: What an amazing, thoughtful, detailed and educational answer. Thank you so much @Molomby for taking the time to write this.